# Probability problem: Determine the probability that the mining company will not be sucessful.

Tags: probability

A mining company is competing for mining rights in a region. The probability of acquiring the rights is $0.4$. If this happens, the probability of it being successful (finding the miner in commercial conditions) is $0.45$. Determine the probability that the company will not be successful.

I tried doing this:
Let $A=$mining company acquire rights, $B=$company being succesful.

$P(A) = 0.4$

$P(B|A) = 0.45$

$P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B|A)=0.4*0.45=0.18$

$1-P(B) = 1-\dfrac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A|B)}=1-\dfrac{0.18}{P(A|B)}$

But I am stuck here, since I don´t know how to find $P(A|B)$. I also tried Bayes rule, but didn´t get any further.

Thanks.

Comment: If the probability of success is $.18$, the probability of failure is $.82$.

Comment: but why is $P(A\cap B)$ the probability of success? ~wouldn´t that be the case only if the events are independent?~ (ignore the part between ~). am I not supposed to find $1-P(B)$ instead of $P(A\cap B)$?

Comment: *instead of $1-P(A \cap B)$

Comment: For the company to succeed, it must acquire the mining rights and the ore must be present in commercial quantities.  That is $A\cap B$. You have computed $\Pr(A\cap B)$ correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You are over-complicating it. It's simple: the probability of being successful once they have acquired de mine rights is 0'45. So the probability of not being successful is 1-0'45=0'55.

Comment: In order to be successful, they must acquire the mining rights.